# Previously working Invoke-restmethod broken in PowerShell v5

Tags: powershell

This snippet of REST API query (Symantec DCS REST API just for fullness of info) used to work like a bought one when running on Windows Server 2008 or 2012.

```
$AssetListUri = "https://" + $UmcHostname + ":4443/sis-ui/api/v1/sa/assets"
$AssetList = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Headers @{Authorization= "bearer 
$AccessToken"; 'Content-Type'='application/json'} -Uri $AssetListUri
```

I'm working on a 2016 server now and it no longer likes me:
[image: Error message]

Yet it works as pictured in postman!
[image: Working in postman]
Has something changed that means my rest api call is no longer supported in powershell?

Comment: It may be that certain insecure cipher suites have been disabled, and the web service doesn't support anything newer, but this is just a guess. You should be able to check the web service with something like SSL Labs, and compare its result to [what's supported on your version of Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374757(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: I think you are right, @briantist but I haven't been able to prove it yet. I'm going to put a trace on the host server and work out specifically why it's dropping the connection. I'll update when I get a chance.